# Dynamic display of labels using thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf and have a requirement of displaying labels dynamically based on database hit.

Suppose we have a column "Race" in our database and table name is "Table1" and the corresponding entity name is "Table1". When user access the html page (home.html) which will hit the table and return the values of field "Race". So if table has 2 values then 2 labels would get display on the page with the values on them and if there are 3 values then 3 labels respectively. I need a Thymeleaf or js code to implement this.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your Java code?

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. But now it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need proper controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String showHome(Model model) {
   List<Table1> list = //Invoke method to get proper rows from db for example use Spring CRUD Repository
   model.addAttribute("list", list);
   return "home"
}
```

Inside of your HTML put:

```
<label th:each="entity: ${list}" th:text="${entity.race}"></label>
```